# firestore query simple get query not working

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I must be doing something stupid as I have written many complex queries but somehow, this query is not working.

```
OnboardingUser Newuser = OnboardingUser();
    try {
      var user = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .doc("EOLjcTCCvMfsi9mnbNynAGwCo723")
          .get();
      print("user: " + user.data().toString());
      Newuser = OnboardingUser.fromFirestore(user, null);
    } catch (e) {
      Logger().e(className + ": " + "getUserByUid: " + e.toString());
    }
```

Here Catch block is not triggered and print is showing null in output i.e.

```
user: null
```

But I have the data in the firestore
[image]

Kindly help.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue might the query might not be returning to user document in the correct format.

Below shows the set up of creating converter for your collection to retrieve an item from your users collection. you will need to have both the fromFirestore and toFirestore functions set up in your OnboardingUser class.

```dart
...
get onboardingUserRef {
    return _db.collection("users").doc(_id).withConverter(
        fromFirestore: OnboardingUser.fromFirestore,
        toFirestore: (OnboardingUser user, _) => user.toFirestore(),
    );
}

whateverYourFunctionIs() async {
    try {
        userRef = await onboardingUserRef.get();
        OnboardingUser user = userRef.data();
    } catch (e) {
        // catch error
    }

}
...
```

Comment: resolved this issue by uninstalling and reinstalling the app. Don't know how, but it started working again. Still thank you.

Comment: lol when in doubt, restart it